# Custom modal dialog component with zk

Tags: zk

i am trying to develop a custom component with ZK with this funcionallity: i want a button that when you click it show a modal dialog with two buttons, "Ok" and "Cancel", and know what button pressed the user.

I had been trying multiples ways but i don't find the solution. Someone did something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you tried. Post your (non-working) code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MessageBox in ZK.
You can know what button pressed with Events.
This is the demo link:

http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/window/message_box